# Chaining issue with map in ruby

Tags: ruby

When I chain like so:

```
self.config["footers"].map({|f| f["name"]}).include?(footer_name)
```

I get:

```
syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end
```

What is it that I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You put the block for `map` in parentheses. Use this instead:

```
self.config["footers"].map {|f| f["name"]}.include?(footer_name)
```

If, for some reason, in general, you run into precedence issues, put parenthesis around the *whole* call:

```
(self.config["footers"].map {|f| f["name"]}).include?(footer_name)
```

Comment: Second point was the issue. It was getting confused with precendence issues.

Answer (score 3):

Don't put `map` block into `()`. It is a block, not a parameter:

```
self.config["footers"].map{|f| f["name"]}.include?(footer_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely must use parentheses due to a management-imposed parentheses quota, you can pass a proc with the ampersand operator to be interpreted as a block.

```
self.config["footers"].map(&proc{|f| f["name"]}).include?(footer_name)
```

While much less clean and pleasing than proper block usage, it does a bang-up job of justifying your parentheses budget to the requisitions committee.